# remove duplicate from array of objects based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects
I have tried to remove a duplicate from the array, but I can't remove it based on a condition
this is the array

```
result = [
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 } 
]
```

what I have done is using the `.filter()` and the `.findIndex()` but I can't get my excepted output
this is what I have done

```
var mm = result.filter(
  (value, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => t.jobId === value.jobId)
);
console.log(mm);
```

my output was

```
[
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 }
]
```

expected output is based on my condition which can be based on higher `acceptableRate` or higher `requiredNumber`

```
[
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 },
  { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
]
```

Comment: Define "duplicate", I don't understand your expected output.

Comment: From the above question it seems to remove duplicate JobID record which have lower acceptable rate in case of equal acceptable rate in jobID remove lower required number record.

Comment: @JitendraPathak yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort the array by `acceptableRate` or if they are the same values by `requiredNumber` then find duplicates. This way.

```js
result = [
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
    { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 },
];

 result.sort(function (a, b) {
     return b.acceptableRate - a.acceptableRate || b.requiredNumber - a.requiredNumber;
 });

var mm = result.filter(
    (value, index, self) =>
        index === self.findIndex((t) => t.jobId === value.jobId),
);

console.log(mm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will filter the values ​​for you if the `jobId` comes first according to `acceptableRate`, and if there are two identical values ​​then it will filter according to `requiredNumber`

```
var mm = result.sort((a, b) => b.jobId < a.jobId ? true : b.jobId > a.jobId ? false : b.acceptableRate > a.acceptableRate ? true : b.acceptableRate < a.acceptableRate ? false : b.requiredNumber - a.requiredNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, here might be the code. We filter out all the items if there's an item with same jobId and higher acceptableRate.

```js
const result = [
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 2, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 3, requiredNumber: 3, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 4, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 80 },
  { jobId: 2, requiredNumber: 1, acceptableRate: 95 } 
];

const finalResult = result.filter(x => 
    !result.find(r => 
        r.jobId === x.jobId && 
        r.acceptableRate > x.acceptableRate));
console.log(finalResult);
```